# Aggregates deduplication by property in Event Sourcing

Tags: validation, .net-core, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I have the aggregate *Product* with properties: *Id, ProductName, ProductPrice and events: ProductCreated, ProductNameChanged, ProductPriceChanged* with commands.

I store my events in *EventStore* and I'm building the actual aggregate state before execute any command, in addition I have the async read model for this aggregate.

How I can **check new product name, that my database has not other product with same name** (in CreateProductCommand or ChangeProductName) ?

I can't use my read model, because it is async and I can't read all events for this aggregate type and build actual models for each product because this operation is expensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few broad approaches (note that I have no direct .Net or EventStore experience, though I've developed event-sourced systems in other stacks for several years now):

- A read model which tracks which product names have been claimed should not be expensive.  Because it would be asynchronously updated, there will be a period of time after a successful creation where the claimed name would not have propagated to that read model.  Product creation and name changing would then be a saga which checks the read model and only passes on a command if that check succeeds.
- One way to address this is to embrace eventual consistency: that read model has the ability to detect after the fact that two products have been created with the same name and begin a process of correction (e.g. it may be possible to augment the domain model to allow one instance to be marked as an alternative ID for the other instance and automatically fuse their accumulated state; alternatively, if that's not possible, manual flagging and intervention will often work).
- Alternatively, if stronger consistency is desired, you can have the name manipulation saga maintain the state of which names it's seen which have not propagated to the read model.  This will put an upper bound on the rate at which names can be manipulated (as all would effectively have to go through a single process to coordinate things)

Note that in the absence of computers, the same decision has to be made: will there be a single person who's in charge of changing product names in the catalog or will we allow multiple people to change names and accept that there's a chance of a conflict (which implies some process for deciding what to do if there's a conflict).  DDD is largely all about "first solve the problem without computers" and then translate that solution into one that uses computers.

If it's allowed to have `ProductName` be an aggregate ID, it may also be viable to have that aggregate just be a mapping from name to product ID.